# Unable to access Camera in dynamically created Webview

Tags: java, android, webview, android-webview

I am trying to access camera through web application. If I create a WebView in XML, it is working fine. But the same doesn't work if I try to create the WebView dynamically. A blank section is coming[ Image attached below]. The Camera Streams are unable to update the view.

This is the WebView Class File

```
public class PageView extends WebView {
public PageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public PageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init();
}

public PageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public void init() { 
    setWebChromeClient(new CustomizedWebChromeClient());
    setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());


    //File access
    getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
    getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);

    //Video playbacks
    getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
    getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);

    setupHardwareAcceleration();

    setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);   
}

class CustomizedWebChromeClient extends android.webkit.WebChromeClient
{
    @Override
    public void onPermissionRequest(PermissionRequest request) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            request.grant(request.getResources());
        }
    }
}

@TargetApi(11)
private void setupHardwareAcceleration() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        if (isHardwareAccelerated()) {
            setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_NONE, null);
        } else {
            setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        }
    }
}}
```

This is the MainActivity Class

```
private WebView webView = null;
private String url = "https://www.onlinemictest.com/webcam-test/";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    addWebViewToActivity();
}

public void addWebViewToActivity() {
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);
    WebView web = new PageView(this);
    web.loadUrl("https://www.onlinemictest.com/webcam-test/");
    ll.addView(web);
}
```

This is the result of the above code.
[image: The number represents the number of frames on the screen]

**Note:** In some websites which tests the webcam, the results of the tests are coming as normal. All the details of my webcam( Android Camera) is also coming as normal. We were even be able to take photos. But the stream from camera to view is not coming. Only as blank. Also, the number in the blank area represents the number of frames.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue.

I thought that the issue is due to the difference between creating WebView dynamically vs from XML. But the real reason for the issue is, When we create a customized WebView like

```
public CustomizedWebView extends WebView
```

and a normal object of Webview like

```
Webview webview = new Webview(context);
```

The difference between both of them is the Layer Type. Layer Type is set as **"LAYER_TYPE_NONE"** for webview. Because of this, I was getting blank screen.